# How do I work with this API, which has an incorrect port in the wsdl?

Tags: php, soap

I am working with an API that does not behave as I would expect it to.

I'm using PHP and soap client to make requests to the API using this WSDL:

https://product.companyurl.co.uk:9450/Product.svc?wsdl

This does not work and causes an error whether I'm using soapui or any PHP soap client configuration I can find on stack overflow.

However, if I remove the port and use:

https://product.companyurl.co.uk/Product.svc?wsdl

I can view the WSDL in my browser and it seems to work.

The problem is that the WSDL references 18 .xsd files within it which also have the same port number in them:

https://product.companyurl.co.uk:9450/Product.svc?xsd=xsd0

Again, the port here stops the url from working in a browser and causes an error in soapui or PHP soap client.

I downloaded the WSDL locally and replaced all occurrences of :9450 in both the WSDL and local copes of the .xsd files.

This worked in soap ui and brought back all the methods and seemed to show promise.

However I can't run any methods using my altered version of the api.

I'm going under the assumption I have got something wrong here.

A simple version of my question would be: why have they added this :9450 to the WSDL which seems to break it, and can I override it connecting to the API so that I can make requests?

For reference, the php error it brings back is:

**Fatal error**:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: can't import schema from 'https://product.companyurl.co.uk:9450/Product.svc?xsd=xsd0'

Thanks

Comment: Have you talked to the people who provide the service?

Comment: They're looking into it but it's been two weeks so I'm wondering if there's a workaround, or if I've simply got something wrong.

Comment: Downloading the WSDL and replacing the references to the XSDs should do the trick, as observed from SoapUI which can eventually load the definitions. You then say *"However I can't run any methods using my altered version of the api"* What do you mean by this? What service endpoint are you calling? Does making calls from SoapUI work?

Comment: Thanks, Bogdan. In soapUI, it opens the wsdl and then all of the .xsd files. Soap UI then shows all of the methods I would like to call in the left panel. However, using these methods does not work. I'm calling the Product endpoint but making calls from soapUI does not work.

Comment: My mistake. I had an issue with an incorrect password. I think it will work now. Thanks